# All finite groups have a composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a group $G$, if $G$ is simple, then $G$ has a trivial composition series. But for $|G| = n$, let us assume that there is a composition series for all groups of lesser order and that $G$ is not simple. So there is a subgroup $N < G$ and since $|N| < |G|$, $N$ has a composition series. 
Let $1 = N_0 < \ldots < N_m = N$, be its composition series. Then $1 = N_0 < \ldots < N_m < N_{m+1} = G$ would be the composition series of $G$. 
Is there a problem with this proof?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question about the validity of your proof: It is the right approach, but I think you are missing something. A composition series isn't just a "series" of normal subgroups. You also need each normal subgroup to be maximal in the sense that each successive quotient is simple. So from your proof this is not clear because you have just formed a "series" of normal subgroups.

You can find the proof just googling the the question will give you several sites that have the right answer.

I think this:

[Every normal subgroup of a finite group is contained in some composition series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191984/every-normal-subgroup-of-a-finite-group-is-contained-in-some-composition-series?rq=1)

might be helpful.